# I want to change a url when I click a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want is when I click on "products-categories" the functions takes it value and put it in my API url and change my products according to new URL. I know the method I am using is wrong so I you can suggest any way of doing it

**Here is the code:**

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import './Allproducts.css'

import ForYouItem from './ForYouItem'

```
export default function Allproducts(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const {category} = props;
    const [cat1, setCat1] = useState(category)
    let cat = `/${cat1}`
    

    useEffect(() => {
        // let cat = {category}
        fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category${cat}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setProducts(data))
    }, [])
    
    let ChangeRoute = (c) => {
       setCat1(c)
     }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="banner">
                <h1>{category}</h1>
                <h4>Get best items in budget</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="main-grid">
                <div className="left-grid">
                    <div className="left-categories">
                        <h1>Collections</h1>
                         <h4 className='products-categories' onClick={ () => {ChangeRoute("electronics")} }>electronics</h4>
                         <h4 className='products-categories' onClick={ () => {ChangeRoute("jewelery")} }>jewelery</h4>
                         <h4 className='products-categories' onClick={ () => {ChangeRoute("men's clothing")} }>men's clothing</h4>
                         <h4 className='products-categories' onClick={ () => {ChangeRoute("women's clothing")} }>women's clothing</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="right-grid">

                    <div className="row ">
                        {products.map((product) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="col-md-4 my-2 Products">
                                    <ForYouItem Title={product.title.slice(0, 21)} Price={product.price} Imageurl={product.image} rate={product.rating.rate} count={product.rating.count} />
                                </div>


                            )

                        }

                        )}



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want to re-invoke the request to your URL any time that value changes, then you would add that value to the `useEffect` dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // let cat = {category}
  fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category${cat}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setProducts(data))
}, [cat1]); // <--- here
```

The operation within a `useEffect` happens when:

- If the dependency array has values, any time one of those values changes
- If the dependency array is empty, once when the component loads
- If the dependency array is omitted, once every render